# How to determine DevMode in React-Native in Native Android Component?

Tags: java, android, debugging, react-native

Is there a similar way to check if I'm in debug mode like there is in Objective-C?

`#ifdef DEBUG
    // ...
  #else
    // ...
  #endif`

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the app runs in development mode:

`if(__DEV__) {
    // do something...
}`